# Find all permutations of smaller string s in string b (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I've been trying to find a O(n) solution to the following problem: Find the number of anagrams (permutations) of string s in string b, where s.length will always be smaller than b.length

I read that the optimal solution involves keeping track of the frequencies of the characters in the smaller string and doing the same for the sliding window as it moves across the larger string, but I'm not sure how that implementation actually works. Right now my solution doesn't work (see comments) but even if it did, it would take O(s + sn) time.

EDIT: Sample input: `('aba', 'abaab')`. Output: 3, because `'aba'` exists in b starting at index 0, and `'baa'` at 1, and `'aab'` at 2.

```
function anagramsInStr(s,b) {

    //O(s)
    let freq = s.split("").reduce((map, el) => {
        map[el] = (map[el] + 1) || 1;
        return map;
    }, {});

    let i = 0, j = s.length;
    // O(n)
    for (let char in b.split("")) {
        // O(s)
        if (b.length - char + 1 > s.length) {

            let window = b.slice(i,j);

            let windowFreq = window.split("").reduce((map, el) => {
                map[el] = (map[el] + 1) || 1;
                return map;
            }, {});
            // Somewhere about here compare the frequencies of chars found in the window to the frequencies hash defined in the outer scope. 
            i++;
            j++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input and expected output? I'm having trouble understanding the goal. (Is it just to check whether `s` can be made from `b`? Or to count the number of ways? Or something else?)

Comment: @smarx Yep! Added sample input and ouput to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the comments and let me know if you have any questions:

```js
function countAnagramOccurrences(s, b) {
  var matchCount = 0;

  var sCounts = {}; // counts for the letters in s
  var bCounts = {}; // counts for the letters in b

  // construct sCounts
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    sCounts[s[i]] = (sCounts[s[i]] || 0) + 1;
  }

  // all letters that occur in sCounts
  var letters = Object.keys(sCounts);

  // for each letter in b
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    // maintain a sliding window
    // if we already have s.length items in the counts, remove the oldest one
    if (i >= s.length) {
      bCounts[b[i-s.length]] -= 1;
    }
    // increment the count for the letter we're currently looking at
    bCounts[b[i]] = (bCounts[b[i]] || 0) + 1;

    // test for a match (b counts == s counts)
    var match = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
      if (sCounts[letters[j]] !== bCounts[letters[j]]) {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
      matchCount += 1;
    }
  }

  return matchCount;
}

console.log(countAnagramOccurrences('aba', 'abaab')); // 3
```

**EDIT**

A note about the runtime: this is sort of O(nk + m), where *n* is the length of *s*, *m* is the length of *b*, and *k* is the number of unique characters in *b*. Since *m* is always less than *n*, we can reduce to O(nk), and since *k* is bounded by a fixed constant (the size of the alphabet), we can further reduce to O(n).